# Dictionary API for a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I would like to have a dictionary for my website where the user can easily fill in a word or better yet right click a word and get the definition right there on the page or something along those lines.

Are there any Dictionary API's out there that I can incorporate to my site? I have looked and cannot find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ProgrammableWeb tracks web APIs & it shows [a useful list when you search with the keyword "dictionary"](http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/?q=dictionary)

[FOLDOC.org](http://foldoc.org/source.html) & [WordNet from Princeton University](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/) provide their dictionary database for free. Customizing the database will require some programming.

Comment: I think Wordnik specifically from that list is trying to grow quite a bit and uses modern techniques. It certainly has an API that could be integrated.