# Adding description for words on your website

Tags: web-development, keywords, api

I am creating a website with a lot of programming language, and words that are related to programming and application development.

Now I like the idea to have a tooltip on certain words, let's say a word like php. When someone rolls over the word a small popup appears with a small text explaining what it is. Stackoverflow uses the same when you roll over a tag.

Is here an API that I can use to get the info on certain words, or should I create it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or similar type javascript/AJAX type stuff. What you trying todo has been done many times before and is available in many open source libraries, just find the right library and use it.

and mix it up with a free service yourself, someone [asked this question before](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18189/dictionary-api-for-a-website)

Comment: Do they supply the text also? Or do you mean the rollover effect only?

Comment: I was talking about roll over effect only, I think you shoud break this question to two questions, one for the roll over part and another for places where one can get text the descriptions from. As matter of fact you can make it as simple as just finding text description for the words i.e. Free dictionary Services. Hell, I ask that question myself.

Comment: @Saif : Updated the answer.

Comment: I was only looking for the description part, I can make the rollover part myself. The final question in the post is:*Is here an API that I can use to get the info on certain words, or should I create it myself.* I'm not looking for the rollover effect, I can make that blindfolded.

Comment: @Saif : What do you mean by certain words? are you talking about using an index?

Comment: I meant just words in a text, and these are all programming related, just like here on SE websites. But I can just use the version 1.1 of the stackexchange API to get their wiki text.